# Migrate getServerSideProps(context) to nextjs13 app dir

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, next-auth

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { req } = context;
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  if (session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/portal",
      },
    };
  }

  // const csrfToken = await getCsrfToken(context);
  const providers = await getProviders();

  return {
    props: { providers },
  };
}
```

in my old index page this is how I would check for a session and either redirect or set props providers.

now in the app directory structure I can no longer use getServerSideProps()

the documentation states to use fetch or an external function, which is fine but how do we use context still in them?

```
const getSessionInfo = async (context: any) => {
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  if (session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/portal",
      },
    };
  }
}

const HomePage = async () => {
  const isSession = await getSessionInfo(context);
```

context doesn't exist now. we need to get the session info so how is everyone doing this with the app dir system in nextjs13?